# Create new column based on corresponding values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
id_a    id_b     col_a
  NaN    NaN     NaN
  0     133     [23]
  7     191     [10,7]
  10    303     [1]
  23    200     [0,7,10]
```

I need to create a new column like so:

```
id_a    id_b     col_a      col_b
  NaN    NaN     NaN          NaN
  0     133     [23]         [200] 
  7     191     [10,7]       [303,191]
  10    303     [1]          [101]
  23    200     [0,7,10]     [133,191,303]
```

The logic is that I am returning the ids from `id_b` based on a corresponding value in `id_a`.

Example: for the first list [1,0,7];

I return 101, from `id_b` since the corresponding value with 1 in `id_b` is 101. Then 133 since 0 matches with 133 and finally 191 since 7 is the corresponding value here.

I have tried using `.loc` to capture just those rows but haven't got far. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

IIUC `explode` then `map`

```
df.col_a.explode().map(dict(zip(df.id_a,df.id_b))).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
0    [101, 133, 191]
1              [200]
2         [303, 191]
3              [101]
4    [133, 191, 303]
Name: col_a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice 1 with explode, should have thought about it

Comment: I just updated the question to include NaNs. Not sure if this still works

Comment: In this case you only need: `df.col_a.explode().map(dict(zip(df.id_a,df.id_b))).dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(list)`. Nice @YO and BEN_W

Comment: @Mazz check above comments ~

Comment: @YO and BEN_W keep getting the error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'. Assume this is something to do with my own dtypes? Which type  did you assume each column to be?

Comment: @Mazz for `explode` to be available you should upgrade to pandas version `0.25+` :)

Answer (score 3):

With `df.stack()`:

```
d = dict(zip(df['id_a'],df['id_b']))
df['col_b'] = (pd.DataFrame(df['col_a'].tolist()).replace(d)
            .stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

Or:
`apply`:

```
df['col_b'] = df['col_a'].apply(lambda x: [d.get(i) for i in x])
print(df)
```

---

```
   id_a  id_b       col_a            col_b
0     1   101   [1, 0, 7]  [101, 133, 191]
1     0   133        [23]            [200]
2     7   191     [10, 7]       [303, 191]
3    10   303         [1]            [101]
4    23   200  [0, 7, 10]  [133, 191, 303]
```